# Cannot access a VCL component in a procedure called from FormCreate on a modal form (i.e. directly after opening the form)

Tags: delphi, access-violation, delphi-10.1-berlin

Running into a runtime error when I open a modal form (Form2) that, on create, calls another procedure that does somehting with a VCL component. The following program demonstrates the issue.

This is the code on the modal form:

```
procedure DoLabel;
begin
  form2.Label1.Caption := 'A';
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoLabel;
end;
```

This compiles well. However, the program crashes on opening the modal form. The debugger says: *access violation at address xxxx*. It is probably a basic error, but what am I doing wrong? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the global `Form2` variable, which has not been assigned yet (or at all) while the `TForm2` object is still being constructed.

You need to change your code to not rely on that variable during construction (and preferably remove it entirely, unless `TForm2` is auto-created at startup, which it does not sound like it is).

For instance, pass the Form's `Self` pointer, or even its `TLabel` pointer, as an input parameter to `DoLabel()`, eg:

```pascal
procedure DoLabel(ALabel: TLabel);
begin
  ALabel.Caption := 'A';
end;

procedure DoFormStuff(AForm: TForm2);
begin
  // use AForm as needed...
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoLabel(Label1);
  DoFormStuff(Self);
end;
```

Though, in this case, it would make more sense to have `DoFormStuff()`, and possible `DoLabel()` too, be a member of the `TForm2` class instead of free functions:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoLabel;
  DoFormStuff;
end;

procedure TForm2.DoLabel;
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'A';
end;

procedure TForm2.DoFormStuff;
begin
  // use Self as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. This works. But still puzzling for me to grasp is why my code did not run. The Form2.ShowModal command on the main form would (in my clearly wrong assumption) be constructing the modal form, including all its components and then,  running the CreateForm procedure.      So, to be sure: there is no other option than the one you showed above, to access form2 components from the CreateForm procedure?

Comment: @Fred As I stated in the very 1st sentence of my answer, the code you showed would crash if the global `Form2` variable has not been assigned yet. For instance, if you use `Form2 := TForm2.Create(...);` then `OnCreate` is called before `Create()` exits, thus `Form2` is not assigned yet when `OnCreate` runs. But, if you use `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);` instead, then the code shown should not crash. However, you really shouldn't be using `CreateForm()` directly for non-AutoCreated forms outside of the project's DPR file, using `Create()` is the preferred way for secondary Forms.